# Как повернуть объект на игрока через ось Z не затрагивая ось X в Unity5?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

[image: Зомби-2д спрайт, который нужно повернуть на игрока]

Помогите пожалуйста! У меня есть 2д зомбик, координаты которого равны координатам 3д сферы, передвижение которой сделано через NavMeshAgent. Я хочу, чтобы при ходьбе его спрайт поворачивался в сторону игрока по оси Z, но из-за необычных осей координат и поворота спрайта на 90 градусов по Х не понимаю, как это реализовать. Функция LookAt() затрагивает ось Х, что мне совершенно не нужно...[image: сам игрок и его координаты]
[image: как это выглядит на сцене]

Answer (score 1):

у функции `LookAt` есть второй параметр, которым вы задаете направление вверх от объекта. Если указать `transform.forward * (-1)` то получим вектор направленный на нас, и если его указать в качеств направления вверх в функции `LookAt`, то объект у вас должен будет вращаться вокруг этого вектора.

Comment: Я думаю, что верх у меня указан правильно, даже если не указывать второй параметр. Просто, функция LookAt на игроке у меня работает корректно (игрок при ходьбе смотрит на пустышку, положение которой равно положение игрока + его скорости), а на самом зомби с этим какие-то проблемы... Если LookAt на игроке оставляет ось X равной 87-90, то на зомби LookAt почему-то изменяет ось Х на 0, и из-за этого спрайт становится не видим для камеры...

Comment: получается так, что мне нужно не трогая ось Х (или сделав поворот на 90) повернуть зомби по оси Z на игрока

Comment: В качестве вверх указывайте ось вверх на зомби, у вас модель там может быть развернута, из за этого и крутиться неправильно. Можно сделать пустой объект и в него поместить модель зомби, и тогда вращать этот контейнер и ошибок быть не должно